# Invalid certificate warning when running the python HTTPServer

Tags: python, https, openssl

I am trying to run the python3 `HTTPServer` with self signed certificates.  I created the self-signed certificates  :

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -nodes -x509 -days 3650 
 -keyout key.localhost.pem -out cert.localhost.pem
```

Then I am using the python `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 
from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
import ssl
import socketserver

import sys
port = int(sys.argv[1])
# httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', port), BaseHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(('localhost', port), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)

keyfile="/Users/steve/key.localhost.pem" ;certfile='/Users/steve/cert.localhost.pem'
httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (httpd.socket, 
       keyfile="/Users/steve/localhost.key", certfile='/Users/steve/localhost.crt', server_side=True)

httpd.serve_forever()
```

Let's try to load something from the web server  at `https://localhost:9443/tests`.

Notice that we get a `Not secure` ..

[image]

Clicking on the Red `Not Secure` we get more info:

[image]

Let's  look at the 'certificate invalid' details:

[image]

[image]

What step(s) did I do incorrectly?

Comment: when I search info in Google then I see `self signed certificates` can't be trusted. You would have to accept exception in web browser to use it. To create trusted cert you would have to generate RootCA - and use it sign your cert. But even here you have to add RootCA to system as trusted cert. And all this for security reason - if you could so easy create tursted cert then hackers would use it. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-https-working-on-your-local-development-environment-in-5-minutes-7af615770eec/

Comment: @furas  Nice link : seems there are several small additional steps to do this properly.  Feel free to make an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I searched for this in Google  I see that `self signed certificates` can't be trusted.
You would have to accept an exception in web browser to use it.

To create the trusted cert you would have to generate a `RootCA` and use it to sign your cert. But even here you have to add the `RootCA` to the system as a trusted cert.

All of this is for security reasons. If you could create a trusted cert so easily then hackers would use it.

---

BTW: One of the link which I found with Gooogle:

[How to get HTTPS working on your local development environment in 5 minutes](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-https-working-on-your-local-development-environment-in-5-minutes-7af615770eec/)